# Static linking cross compiled QAxcontainer

Tags: c++, qt, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile an application with the gnu make toolchain. Previously I have already successfully compiled Qt and the QAxContainer module. I appear to be setting all the required environment variables. 
Using libtool I link my application with the following command:

```
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CXX --tag CXX  --mode=link /home/test/Gridcoin-Research/depends/x86_64-w64-mingw32/share/../native/bin/ccache x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=c++11 -Wstack-protector -fstack-protector-all   -pipe -O2   -pthread  -Wl,--dynamicbase -Wl,--nxcompat -Wl,--high-entropy-va -mwindows -all-static -L/home/test/Gridcoin-Research/depends/x86_64-w64-mingw32/share/../lib  -o qt/gridcoinresearch.exe qt/qt_gridcoinresearch-bitcoin.o  qt/res/bitcoin-qt.o qt/libgridcoinqt.a  leveldb/libleveldb.a  leveldb/libmemenv.a -L/home/test/Gridcoin-Research/depends/x86_64-w64-mingw32/share/../lib -lboost_system-mt-s -lboost_filesystem-mt-s -lboost_program_options-mt-s -lboost_thread_win32-mt-s -lboost_chrono-mt-s -lqwindows -lqminimal -lQt5Concurrent -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Network -lQt5Gui     -lQt5Core    -lqtharfbuzzng -lqtpcre -lqtpng -lz  -lQt5AxServer -lQt5AxContainer -limm32  -L/home/test/Gridcoin-Research/depends/x86_64-w64-mingw32/share/../lib -L/home/test/Gridcoin-Research/depends/x86_64-w64-mingw32/share/../plugins/platforms -lQt5DBus -L/home/test/Gridcoin-Research/depends/x86_64-w64-mingw32/share/../lib -lqrencode  -ldb_cxx-4.8 -lssl -lcrypto -lminiupnpc -lcurl     -lQt5PlatformSupport -lssp -lcrypt32 -liphlpapi -lshlwapi -lmswsock -lws2_32 -ladvapi32 -lrpcrt4 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32 -lcomctl32 -lshell32 -lwinmm -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingwthrd
```

The application already successfully compiles for linux builds, where the AxContainer module is not required. The two relevant linking errors are:

```
undefined reference to `QMetaStringTable::enter(QByteArray const&)'
undefined reference to `QVariantToVoidStar(QVariant const&, void*, QByteArray const &, unsigned int)'
```

Is it even possible to properly cross compile the QAxContainer?

Edit: The build is not done with a standard .pro file, but with the gnu automake toolchain. Only when cross compiling to windows is the qaxcontainer included. I compile ActiveQt statically and then link it during the build process. During the process configure checks for the presence of the QAxContainer and is able to find a main entry point.

Comment: What puzzles me is that if it is cross-compilation then it implies one source for both Windows (where QAxContainer makes sense) and other platforms (where there is no ActiveX and no QAxContainer)?

Comment: There is one source for Windows and other platforms, however the application has extended functionality on Windows where it uses the com interface to communicate with a separate visual basic application.

Comment: You should not compile none of QAxContainer-related stuff for platforms other than Windows because you won't be able to link it with your executable.

Comment: But it should work if I cross compile a windows build? I am not trying to link the QAxcontainer module for a linux application. The Active X support is not needed when running the app on other platforms. It is only linked when building for a windows target.

Comment: Oh, then "cross-compiled" is a bit of distraction. It is just a problem with your Windows build then. I can guess either static Qt was built with no ActiveQt or maybe .pro file is lacking `CONFIG += activeqt`? Maybe it is no in win32 section (if there is same project file for different platforms)?

Comment: I do cross compile. In practice I run the process on Ubuntu 16.04 for each linux, mac and windows plattforms. The windows build fails with the aforementioned linking error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Qt5AxBase library was missing and that the linking was done in the incorrect order. To link The QAxContainer properly in a self managed environment the following link flags need to be included in order:

```
-lQt5AxContainer -lQt5AxBase
```